# Simple constant memory example not working

Tags: cuda, nvidia

Please help me why below not working. In my comp, it just prints 0 when I try to print the value of var.

```
#include<stdio.h>
__constant__ float pivot;

__global__ void kernel(float *set){
        *set = pivot;


}

void main(){
    float c[] = {1,3,4};
    cudaError_t err = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(pivot,&c[2], sizeof(float));
    /*
    float test;
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&test,pivot,sizeof(float));
    printf("the value of test is %f",test);
    */
    if(err!=0){
        printf("some error\n");
        getchar();
    }
    float *st;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&st, sizeof(float));
    kernel<<<1,1>>>(st);
    float *var = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(var, st, sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("the value of st is %f",var);
    getchar();


}
```

Comment: Well var is a pointer, not a float, you probably want to print *var...

Comment: @Dan: Thanks. That fixed it. Post is as an answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 3):

`var` is a `float *`, so when you call `printf("... %f, var);`, you are actually sending the address of the memory allocated by `(float*)malloc(sizeof(float))`.

P.s. I can't edit the post, but shouldn't the tags be `c` and `printf`, as the problem/question has very little to do with `nvidia` or `cuda` (apart from the fact that the two are referenced in the code).